# Use an Accumulator on an Extension

Tags: c#, .net, range

I have the following Range class and extension:

```
public class Range<T> where T : IComparable<T> {
  public T Minimum { get; set; }
  public T Maximum { get; set; }

  public Range(T minimum, T maximum) {
    Minimum = minimum;
    Maximum = maximum; 
  } // Range
}

public static IEnumerable<T> Expand<T>(this Range<T> range, Func<T, T> accumulator) where T : IComparable<T> {

  T current = range.Minimum;

  while (current.CompareTo(range.Maximum) <= 0) {
    yield return current;
    current = accumulator(current);
  }

}
```

I am trying create custom way of expanding Ranges. For example:

```
Range<Int32> range = new Range<Int32>(20, 24);
List<Int32> expect = new List<Int32> { 40, 21, 44, 23, 48 };
List<Int32> result = range.Expand(x => x % 2 == 0 ? x + 1 : x).ToList();
Assert.Equal(expect, result);
```

When I run this code I get the exception:

```
Array dimensions exceeded supported range
```

The same happens if I, for example, use:

```
List<Int32> result = range.Expand(x => 2 * x).ToList();
```

What would be the correct way to create this extension?

**UPDATE**

My work works if using:

```
List<Int32> result = range.Expand(x => ++x).ToList();
```

But I get the same exception when using:

```
List<Int32> result = range.Expand(x => x++).ToList();
```

Why is that?

Comment: Your code will produce 20, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, ... until end of time or maximum range of array

Comment: What if T is a class? How do you define a range with a class?

Comment: Does your implementation have a constructor?

Comment: @SirRufo: I see ... Because it is adding to the previous one ... But is a better way to do this instead of using an accumulator?

Comment: @dotctor T is a generic ... But in my example I use Int32

Comment: @EvanTrimboli Just added the constructor to range class

Comment: You should navigate to next element in your range in every time your `while` loop execute.

Comment: Your extension is correct, the accumulator is the problem. For odd numbers the numbers dont get changed and it becomes "stuck". Thats what @SirRufo told you.

Comment: To your update: Use the debugger, which is very narrative, and watch the values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you are not getting next item in your range. when you have `++x` in the accumulator then it does the job for you. You should move to next item in your `while` loop. Since you are using a generic `Range<T>` you must define how to get next item.

I think the most suitable name for this is **map** not **accumulator**.

```
public class Range<T>
{
    public T Minimum { get; set; }
    public T Maximum { get; set; }
    public Func<T, T> Next { get; set; }
    public Range(T min, T max) { Minimum = min; Maximum = max; }
}

public static IEnumerable<T> Expand<T>(this Range<T> range, Func<T, T> map) where T : IComparable<T>
{
    T current = range.Minimum;
    while (current.CompareTo(range.Maximum) <= 0)
    {
        var result = map(current);
        yield return result;
        current = range.Next(current);
    }
}


Range<Int32> range = new Range<Int32>(20, 24);
range.Next = x => x + 1;
List<Int32> expect = new List<Int32> { 40, 21, 44, 23, 48 };
List<Int32> result = range.Expand(x => x % 2 == 0 ? x * 2 : x).ToList();
Assert.Equal(expect, result);
```